# Debugging Retrofit2 in Eclipse , OKhttp interceptor not displaying log info

Tags: java, eclipse, api, debugging, retrofit

I'm calling a google cloud platform API in a Java project (in Eclipse) with Retrofit2, but the onFaliure method seems to always be called.

So I setup an okhttp interceptor to see if I'm receiving the response or not, but I get nothing!

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build(); // added for logging

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client) // for logging
                .build();
                service = retrofit.create(GoogleLandmarkApi.class);
                return service;
```

in postman I can get a response, so the key I'm using and the base url are correct, the parameters are the same, even if any of those was wrong, I would expect at least some log from the server with an error.

I think I should debug to check if the request has been sent correctly, but I'm not getting anything from the interceptor.

How can I debug this?

Comment: If the `onFailure()` is called the problem is probably not that the server doesn't accept your request. It's usually a fundamental problem. It could be that you can't connect to the server (wrong URL? no internet connection?) or that your converters cannot parse the request/response. You should check the error in the onFailure for more information. See also: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-detect-network-and-conversion-errors-in-onfailure

Comment: Spot on, conversion error. Thanks

Comment: This time I'm getting connection error, although in an external httpClient I can connect ok (from the same computer), any pointers on what that could be?